# Validation Summary and form validation problem ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, validation

I am working on an old project that I am trying to update and add some stuff to and ran into an issue with a form I am trying to validate.

I have tried to add a RequiredValidator field to all the form fields but it did not work. I noticed that the project was using "SX:VInput" and I have never seen this before so it is stumping me. The code is below:

```
Checkout.Aspx

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/Store.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Checkout.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="SportsStore.Pages.Cart.Checkout" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" runat="server">
    <div id="content">

        <div id="checkoutForm" class="checkout" runat="server">
            <h2>Checkout Now</h2>
            Please enter your details, and we'll ship your goods right away!

        <div id="errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
            <ul>
                <li style="display:inline"></li>
            </ul>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="BulletList" ShowMessageBox="true"/>
        </div>

            <h3>Ship to</h3>
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <SX:VInput Property="Name" ID="Name" runat="server"/>


            </div>

            <h3>Address</h3>
            <div>
                <label for="line1">Line 1:</label>
                <SX:VInput Property="Line1" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="line2">Line 2:</label>
                <SX:VInput Property="Line2" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <SX:VInput Property="City" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="state">State:</label>
                <SX:VInput Property="State" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="postalcode">Postal Code:</label>
                <SX:VInput Property="PostalCode" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <h3>Account Information</h3>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <SX:VInput Property="Email" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <SX:VInput Property="Password" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <h3>Options</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" id="giftwrap" name="giftwrap" value="true" />
            Gift wrap these items?

        <p class="actionButtons">
            <button class="actionButtons" type="submit">Complete Order</button>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div id="checkoutMessage" runat="server">
            <h2>Thanks!</h2>
            Thanks for placing your order. We'll ship your goods as soon as possible.    
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>


Vinput.cs




    namespace SportsStore.Controls

    {

    public class VInput : WebControl
    {
        private string nspace = "SportsStore.Models";
        private string model = "Order";

        public string Namespace
        {
            get { return nspace; }
            set { nspace = value; }
        }
        public string Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { model = value; }
        }

        public string Property { get; set; }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {

            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, Property.ToLower());
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, Property.ToLower());

            Type modelType = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1}", Namespace, Model));
            PropertyInfo propInfo = modelType.GetProperty(Property);
       //     var attr = propInfo.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>(false);
       //     if (attr != null)
       //     {
       //         output.AddAttribute("data-val", "true");
       //         output.AddAttribute("data-val-required", attr.ErrorMessage);
       //     }
            output.RenderBeginTag("input");
            output.RenderEndTag();
        }

        public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
        }

        public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this form to validate before sending to the server? It just submits without validating right now and I need to validate. Thank you.

Comment: If your question is "How can I get this form to validate before sending to the server?"  this can be achieved with javascript. Generally speaking js validation is to help the user e.g "Phone Number is not in a valid format" where as backend validation should be used for security

Comment: @JKerny There is a validation summary control already on the page that is not working properly. I would like to try and use the validation summary control if possible.